# understanding the basic definition

Tags: graph-theory

I was going through a topic on *Product Graphs*. I have a very small doubt in the definiton of *Lexicographic Product*. It is defined as follows.....

Given graphs $G_1, G_2, \ldots, G_k$, we define

$G_1 \circ G_2 \circ \cdots \circ G_k$ as follows: the vertex set is $V(G_1) \times V(G_2) \times \cdots \times V(G_k)$, and two
vertices $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k), (y_1, y_2, . . . , y_k)$ are adjacent if for some index $j \in \{1, 2, \ldots, k \}$ we
have $x_j y_j \in E(G_j)$ and $x_i = y_i$ for each $1 \leq i < j$.

**My doubt is :** If we take $k = 8$, and $j=4$, then we will compare $x_i = y_i$ for $i =1,2,3$ only?? What about others,

Can anybody explain me. I would be thankful.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, if you have written out the definition correctly, then it says you only need $x_i=y_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, and what happens for $i\ge5$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ... means its on us to find that $j$ which satisfies the above property. Am I right sir?

Comment: That would be my understanding, yes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok.... thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Consider general lexicographic orderings first and then the definition makes sense: just think of the way you look for words in a lexicon or dictionary: 'artistic' comes before 'interior' with $k=8, j=1$, while 'interior' comes for 'intraday', $k=8, j=4$. You don't know $j$ beforehand and it may vary.